# How to Combine two Dstreams using Pyspark (similar to .zip on normal RDD)

Tags: apache-spark, zip, streaming, pyspark, dstream

I know that we can combine(like cbind in R) two RDDs as below in pyspark:

```
rdd3 = rdd1.zip(rdd2)
```

I want to perform the same for two Dstreams in pyspark. Is it possible or any alternatives?

In fact, I am using a MLlib randomforest model to predict using spark streaming.
In the end, I want to combine the feature Dstream & prediction Dstream together for further downstream processing.

Thanks in advance.

-Obaid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I am using below.

The trick is using "native python map" along with "spark spreaming transform". 
May not an elegent way, however it works :).

```
def predictScore(texts, modelRF):
    predictions = texts.map( lambda txt :  (txt , getFeatures(txt)) ).\
     map(lambda (txt, features) : (txt ,(features.split(','))) ).\
     map( lambda (txt, features) : (txt, ([float(i) for i in features])) ).\
     transform( lambda  rdd: sc.parallelize(\
       map( lambda x,y:(x,y), modelRF.predict(rdd.map(lambda (x,y):y)).collect(),rdd.map(lambda (x,y):x).collect() )\
       )\
     )
    # in the transform operation: x=text and y=features
    # Return will be tuple of (score,'original text')
    return predictions
```

Hope, it will help somebody who is facing same problem.
If anybody has better idea, please post it here.

-Obaid

Note: I also submitted the problem on spark user list and post my answer there as well.

Comment: could you also write the solution in scala?