# Concatenate strings from two different RDD in Python Spark

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, concatenation, rdd

Let's say I have 2 rdds :
the first rdd is composed of strings which are html requests :

**rdd1 :**

```
serverIP:80 clientIP1 - - [10/Jun/2016:10:47:37 +0200] "GET /path/to/page1 [...]"
serverIP:80 clientIP2 - - [11/Jun/2016:11:25:12 +0200] "GET /path/to/page2 [...]"
...
```

The second rdd is simply integers :

**rdd2 :**

```
0.025
0.56
...
```

I would like to concatenate the string lines by lines in order to obtain a third rdd like this :
**rdd3 :**

```
serverIP:80 clientIP1 - - [10/Jun/2016:10:47:37 +0200] "GET /path/to/page1 [...]" 0.025
serverIP:80 clientIP2 - - [11/Jun/2016:11:25:12 +0200] "GET /path/to/page2 [...]" 0.56
...
```

By the way, this job is a streaming job. It's to say, I don't want to store permanently the data in some kind of sql table or something else.

Any idea on how to tackle this ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :** For people trying to join Dstream and not rdd, have a look at this : [How to Combine two Dstreams using Pyspark (similar to .zip on normal RDD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466361/how-to-combine-two-dstreams-using-pyspark-similar-to-zip-on-normal-rdd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on the sequence of the two rdd's to match you can use zip:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("a", "b", "c"))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List(1.1, 1.2, 1.3))

val rdd3 = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map({case (s, d) => s + " " + d})

rdd3.collect() foreach println

// a 1.1
// b 1.2
// c 1.3
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ! No doubt that it should work, but unfortunately I discovered that I use Dstream and not RDD. Do you have any hints on how to adapt you method ? I am trying to extract the rdds from the Dstream currently !